# How can I tag certain value based on value of previous rows in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The data looks like this:

```
Ctgr
A
B
B
C
D
E
F
```

What the result that I am looking for is:

```
Ctgr|subctgr
  A |  A
  B |  A
  B |  A
  C |  A
  D |  D
  E |  D
  F |  D
```

That is to say that subctgr is determined by the value of the first row of each "group".
However, I do not know how to distinguish each "group" in python, though they are separated by a NaN value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist test missing rows by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), then get first values of `groups` by compare with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values of mask and create new column filled by previous values by `ffill`. Last set new column by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#for test missing values
m = df['Ctgr'].isna()
#for test emtsy strings
#m = df['Ctgr'].eq('')
df['subctgr'] = np.where(m,np.nan,df['Ctgr'].where(m.ne(m.shift())).ffill())
print (df)
  Ctgr subctgr
0    A       A
1    B       A
2    B       A
3    C       A
4  NaN     NaN
5    D       D
6    E       D
7    F       D
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(m = df['Ctgr'].isna(),
                 mask = m.ne(m.shift()),
                 first = df['Ctgr'].where(m.ne(m.shift())),
                 ffill = df['Ctgr'].where(m.ne(m.shift())).ffill(),
                 subctgr = np.where(m,np.nan,df['Ctgr'].where(m.ne(m.shift())).ffill())))
  Ctgr      m   mask first ffill subctgr
0    A  False   True     A     A       A
1    B  False  False   NaN     A       A
2    B  False  False   NaN     A       A
3    C  False  False   NaN     A       A
4  NaN   True   True   NaN     A     NaN
5    D  False   True     D     D       D
6    E  False  False   NaN     D       D
7    F  False  False   NaN     D       D
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using pandas `apply` method, i presume if the character is `<='C'` then you want to put `'A'`, otherwise `'D'`.

Assuming that the name of the dataframe is `df` :

```
df['subctgr'] = df['Ctgr'].apply(lambda x: 'A' if x<='C' else 'D')
```

The output would be like :

```
  Ctgr subctgr
0    A       A
1    B       A
2    B       A
3    C       A
4    D       D
5    E       D
6    F       D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
# create a group counter column
df['Counter'] = df['Ctgr'].isna().cumsum()

# drop NA
df2 = df[df['Ctgr'].notna()].reset_index(drop=True)

# join cols
def solve(f):
    # filter data
    f['col'] = f['Ctgr'].apply(lambda x: x + '|' + f['Ctgr'].iloc[0])
    return f

df2 = df2.groupby('Counter').apply(solve)

  Ctgr  Counter  col
0    A        0  A|A
1    B        0  B|A
2    B        0  B|A
3    C        0  C|A
4    D        1  D|D
5    E        1  E|D
6    F        1  F|D
```